# Memoryleak with pointer to pointer, C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to do a Phonehandler system for a class I'm taking, The task specifies that we use a pointer to pointer for the Phone objects in the Phonehandler-class, and that the array to store Phones has a size of two phones from the start and that it can be expanded later. My relevant(?) code is as follow:

**PhoneHandler.h**

```
Phone **phones;
```

**PhoneHandler.cpp (constructor)**

```
PhoneHandler::PhoneHandler()
{
this->phones = new Phone*;
*phones = new Phone[2];
}
```

My code includes some more things than this, but I have not written "new" at any other place so the memoryleaks are allocated in the constructor. I've made a destructor as followed:

**PhoneHandler.cpp (destructor)**

```
PhoneHandler::~PhoneHandler()
{
delete[] phones;
delete phones
}
```

But it's crashing at the first line in the destructor. So I need help with ether the constructor or the destructor, maybe both. Feel free to ask me for more code if it's necessary, but I think that the problem is somewhere in this code. Thanks

Comment: `delete[] *phones;` to be coherent with constructor.

Comment: BTW, Don't forget rule of 5/3/0 too. (copy/move/assignment).

Comment: Don't try to be a [Three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). The extra indirection is useless and hurtful (as you see), and dynamically allocated arrays are just bad practice. There's `std::vector`.

Comment: You delete `phones` twice. You, obviously, don't allocate `phones` twice. (Because `phones` has a value that cannot have been returned from two different allocation calls.)

Comment: If I only have delete[] *phones I'm getting "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" as a error message. But I still have memoryleaks

Answer (score 0):

`delete [] phomes` wont lead to any crash.

`delete phomes` is causing the crash.

Comment: If I only have delete[] phones, it gives me "Heap corruption detected" as error message instead but I still have the memoryleaks

Comment: `delete [] phones` is UB as `phones` is allocated by `new` and not `new[]`